# Redirection or Refresh Page After Zip Download

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I am calling the servlet through href in my .vm file(as I am using velocity framwork for front end) when the request goes to servlet I am downloading a file on that. The file genration for downloading in takes around 30 seconds so I want to indicate end user through pop-up, For this I have called a function on same href in my .vm file which is opening a pop up indicating that file is generating currently so please wait. but when file generation and downloading finish I want to remove that pop up. I was tried this through redirection on servlet but after googled I found that we can't change the status of response after downloading ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596657/downloading-files-from-servlets-chrome-warning-how-to-redirect-user-after-do)).

I am calling javascript function and servlet in my vm file like this

```
 <a href="/overriderulehandler?report=1" onClick="return reportResponse()"> Generate Report </a>
```

overriderulehandler is calling my servlet and I am preparing file for download here and reportResponse is JS function in which I am opening popup.

Please suggest me how should I do this task. If anyone have other idea about this please share. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds a good question and interesting for me. I tried to get some working solution but couldn't figure it out. Looks like there are no simpler way to achieve it. Check these links: 
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921797/jsp-download-file-with-ajax
2) http://www.coderanch.com/t/362152/Servlets/java/Redirect-JSP-file-download
3) http://www.coderanch.com/t/579820/JSF/java/JSP-page-refreshed-successful-csv
4) http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/32282-download-then-show-page-jsp.html

Comment: Can you or are you using jquery?  It's possible to use it to monitor the status code of a resource query, but I've never tried to use jquery ajax to download a resource.  With it, you could potentially set your window.location.href when the success: function on the ajax call is fired.

Comment: Carter I tired to download through ajax but I was not succeed through that.If you have any good link please share with me.

Comment: Please check the first link of shailesh which is saying that we cann't download resource through ajax.

Comment: Ok, understood.  I had not tried it myself @kailashgaur.  I did notice on apple.com, downloading itunes goes directly to the "thankyou" page after starting the download.  Knowing that it's possible, I'll see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: I also check apple.com site, when we click on download now link it directly redirects on Thank you page means somehow it's calling function on onclick of "download now" link or something like this. In my case the report is generating in backend and then save pop up appears. The flow is like when I am clicking on generate report then report start to generate and then download and I want to check that when pop up appears I can refresh my page or redirect somehow.

Comment: How long does your report take to generate?  Per my suggestion in my answer below, you could mitigate this with the text you display to the user, e.g. "Please wait..."  The file download should kick off report generation and that activity, I believe, should remain "open" waiting for the content from the server until the file download completes or the connection is lost.

Answer (score 1):

This onClick handler works for me.

```
onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='test.html'},100)"
```

You can put it in your anchor tag that calls your servlet and the encapsulated anonymous function can call any other function you like.  'test.html' could be a page that says "Your file is being prepared and will download shortly.

The content type of the response on the servlet should match the file type you are pushing so that the browser knows to download the file rather than try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

The method I found to redirect after download is to use two different html/javascript/JQuery event handlers. The redirect handler is the the download even is Onmousedown. So, on mouse down the js will generate a PDF and download, then on mouse up the redirect will execute. Thanks be to God it works...pretty simple to implement too.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmousedown="javascript:createPDF(<?php echo $ID; ?>,'actionName','pageName'); return false;">Create PDF</a>
```

Blessings!